# Absolute Software vs Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualization

If a laptop has Computrace/Absolute software installed and I host a VM there, would the Computrace/Absolute software be able to track whatever they track on the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the press release: https://www.absolute.com/company/press-releases/2009/computrace-by-absolute-software-now-supported-in-firmware-of-getac-computers/

> Computrace software is embedded in the firmware of computers right at the factory for tamper-resistance.2 The stealthy Computrace Agent is capable of surviving operating system re-installations as well as hard-drive reformats, replacements and re-imaging.

> Absolute Monitoring Center, allowing the Absolute Theft Recovery Team to forensically mine the computer using a variety of procedures including key captures, registry scanning, file scanning, geolocation, and other investigative techniques to determine who has the computer and how it is being used.

Yes, it would have access to:

- VM's virtual harddrive file
- Dump of the computers memory ... which would contain the VMs memory
- All Network traffic from either the Physical or VM

They might have to jump through a few hoops to do some of this ... but it wouldn't be far fetched for all of this to be possible if they are tapping the firmware itself.

Comment: So there is NO way to workaround this software right?

Comment: I mean, it all depends on who is managing it ... but yah, assuming they are making full use of the access they have via the hardware ... there is not way of working around it (short of flashing the hardware, re-imaging the computer, and possibly breaking out a soldering iron).